# JWPlayer vs Custom Player

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, jwplayer

I'm playing around with HTML5 videos and front end work. I'm wondering, why use JWPlayer or any other plugin instead of (extensively) creating your own? Other than it being less work.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers, devices, advertising standards, etc are constantly changing, making it essentially impossible to responsibly keep up with the rapidly moving market AND continue to develop on top of the player (which, if you look at building a player from a macro perspective, is where the work really begins).

In short, using a product like JW Player gives you all of those benefits on top of the `<video>` tag without requiring you to become an expert in video engineering.